# Jquery - Stop for if condition

Tags: jquery, for-loop

I can not stop the for loop so that there was only the first input text that is colored red if it is empty and it turns green if filled. I try with if in the for loop but I'm missing something. http://jsfiddle.net/4dvw6/1/

```
$(document).on('click', '#Check', Check);

function Check() {
    var length = $('#PA .argument').length;
    for (i = 1; i < length + 1; i++) {
        var val = $("#PA tr:eq(" + i + ")").find(".argument").val();
        if (val === "") {
            $("#PA tr:eq(" + i + ")").find(".argument").css('background', 'red')
        } else if (val !== "") {
            $("#PA tr:eq(" + i + ")").find(".argument").css('background', 'green')
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can replace `else if (val !== "")` with `else`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [break](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break)

```
if (val === "") {
    $("#PA tr:eq(" + i + ")").find(".argument").css('background', 'red');
    break;//break for loop here
}
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/kq8MW/)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/4dvw6/2/

```
$(document).on('click', '#Check', Check);

function Check() {
var length = $('#PA .argument').length;
for (i = 1; i < length + 1; i++) {
    var val = $("#PA tr:eq(" + i + ")").find(".argument").val();
    if (val === "") {
    $("#PA tr:eq(" + i + ")").find(".argument").css('background', 'red')
    break;//return;
    }else {
    $("#PA tr:eq(" + i + ")").find(".argument").css('background', 'green')
    }

}
}
```

Comment: don't use return, use break. Here you will return from check function, which means any following code after `for` loop will be skipped. That's seems ok here because there is no following code but it's calling for trouble if code change in futur